# Can I modify my DIV to ensure all contents fit - When using this CSS to center said div?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Hopefully this is not a duplicate and is actually unique - I couldn't find anything that matched my exact case.

I am using the following code (found this from a quick google search) to have a modal window that pops up adjust itself to the center of the screen.

```
.editModal {
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 50% !important;
  left: 50% !important;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

Everything looks the way it should when the browser is set to 90% zoom but when I go to 100% it starts to mess up.  The modal itself stays the same width (it get's longer and a scroll bar appears but I need it just get wider and keep the same height).

I did another search and tried setting

```
overflow: auto;
```

In an attempt to have the modal window, which is a div, stretch to fit everything but that did not work to make it wider.  It did make it longer and added a scroll bar, but as noted above that is not how I would like to handle it.

I'll attach some images as well to better show what is happening.

[image: How I need it to display]

[image: How the modal changes when the zoom is modified]

Comment: Wrap your modal content in a div with a min width and then give your modal overflow auto and then it should work better

Comment: @Pete I wrapped the original outer DIV inside another one and added those properties but nothing changed.  However when I changed the original outer DIV and added those properties it did modify it.  I could make it as wide as I pleased but if I zoomed in too much the overlapping came back, as well as the scroll bar.

Comment: wrap the contents not the outer div, if you wrap the outer div you just break things. and the overlapping, that's why you need a min-width on that wrapper div

Comment: @Pete thank you very much for the help!